# Changing workspace leads to 'NoneType' error

Tags: arcpy

I've written the following code to process files within 2 separate folders, 'Daily Max 2015' and 'Daily Min 2015'. The workspace is set to: "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles". With this, the code works.

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Set workspace to Max Temps folder and allow for overwrite
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"

#Get Max Temp shapefiles and convert them to Raster
shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
for shpFile in shpFileList:
    # geoprocessing steps
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + ".tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Max_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)

    #Get raster files and run through Raster Calculator to see if Max  threshold has been met
    rastFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.tif")
    for rastFile in rastFileList:
        #geoprocessing steps
        rastFileName = os.path.splitext (rastFile) [0]
        MaxRstIn = Raster(rastFile)
        MaxRstOut = Con(MaxRstIn, 1, 0, "VALUE <=85")
        MaxRstOut.save("Con" + rastFile)

 #Set workspace to Min Temps folder and allow overwrite 
 env.overwriteOutput = True
 env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\DailyMin2015"

 #Loop through Min Temp shapefiles and convert them to Raster
 shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
 for shpFile in shpFileList:
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + ".tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Min_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)

    #Loop through raster files and run through Raster Calculator to see if Min threshold has been met
    rastFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.tif")
    for rastFile in rastFileList:
        rastFileName = os.path.splitext (rastFile) [0]
        MinRstIn = Raster(rastFile)
        MinRstOut = Con(MinRstIn, 1, 0, "VALUE >=45")
        MinRstOut.save("Con" + rastFile)
```

I need to find the sum of the each corresponding Daily Max and Daily Min file so I brought them together in a '2015' file and run Cell Statistics. Accordingly, I changed the workspace to: "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Set workspace to Max Temps folder and allow for overwrite
env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"

#Get Max Temp shapefiles and convert them to Raster
shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
for shpFile in shpFileList:
    # geoprocessing steps
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + ".tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Max_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)

    #Get raster files and run through Raster Calculator to see if Max  threshold has been met
    rastFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.tif")
    for rastFile in rastFileList:
        #geoprocessing steps
        rastFileName = os.path.splitext (rastFile) [0]
        MaxRstIn = Raster(rastFile)
        MaxRstOut = Con(MaxRstIn, 1, 0, "VALUE <=85")
        MaxRstOut.save("Con" + rastFile)

 #Set workspace to Min Temps folder and allow overwrite 
 env.overwriteOutput = True
 env.workspace = "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMin2015"

 #Loop through Min Temp shapefiles and convert them to Raster
 shpFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.shp")
 for shpFile in shpFileList:
    shpFileName = os.path.splitext (shpFile)[0]
    rastFile = shpFileName + ".tif"
    arcpy.PointToRaster_conversion(shpFile, "Min_2015", rastFile, "MOST_FREQUENT", "", 0.05)

    #Loop through raster files and run through Raster Calculator to see if Min threshold has been met
    rastFileList = arcpy.ListFiles("*.tif")
    for rastFile in rastFileList:
        rastFileName = os.path.splitext (rastFile) [0]
        MinRstIn = Raster(rastFile)
        MinRstOut = Con(MinRstIn, 1, 0, "VALUE >=45")
        MinRstOut.save("Con" + rastFile)
```

But, with this one change, I get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\Python\Script3.py", line 12, in 
    for shpFile in shpFileList:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

The data are there - any thoughts on why this error? I'm working with Python 2.7 and ArcGIS 10.3

Comment: Are there are definitely shapefiles in C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles?

Comment: @Fezter, yes there are. All I did was make a '2015' folder and move the 'Daily Max/Min folders' into it.

Comment: What happens if you print shpFileList before your for loop? What's in the list? My guess is that there is something there that shouldn't be.

Comment: Does arcpy.Exists(env.workspace) return True? Usually, you need to put an r before windows filepath strings, so maybe try `env.workspace = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015\Shapefiles"`

Comment: @KJYDavis, putting the 'r' before did the trick. So simple! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an r (raw string) before [windows filepath strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

```
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\DailyMax2015\Shapefile‌​s"
```